# How to - Allow only one set of people to view certain type of Cases

Tags: case, sharing, sharing-rule

I have a scenario: Lets say there are 2 groups of users in the same profile ( Group A And group B). And there are 2 types of Cases - A and B(other Cases).

> **What I want** :

There is no restriction on Case Creation but Only Group A is authorized to see the cases of types A.

> **Solution that I think** :

1. Create 2 record types.
2. Set the Org wide defaults for 'case' as private.
3. Create 2 Sharing rules for case: 
   Group A have Read/Write access to Cases A and Group B have read/write access to Case B.
4. Create different page layouts for both groups and do the assignment according to the record type.

Can anyone please advise if this solution looks fine or can propose better solution as I don't want to create one more profile?
All suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach is good and profile does not govern visibility of records.

One suggestion around this:

Either you can create role based sharing or public group based sharing. Here public group based sharing is also good.

For criteria based sharing you can specify any fields like, record type or case type or any custom fields based on which you can define the conditions.

Please verify that record type is really needed in this situation.

If you like to show all the same fields, same picklist values and same page layout to both the user groups then separate page layouts are not needed. As same page layouts can be assigned for 2 different record types.

If you like to show different picklist values of same picklist field and different fields on the page layout then you can think of different record types.

Also, think about the reporting need when you are coming out any solutions.

Comment: Thanks Santanu for your suggestion! Yes, I will be using different page layouts for my case.